# Конвертировать Hex в ASCII

Tags: java, android, hex, ascii

Нужно преобразовать строку Hex `4E A8 40 74 00 53 E0` в строку ASCII `N @t S` .

Нигде не могу найти код, если кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Просто используйте цикл for, чтобы пройти через каждую пару символов в строке, преобразовать их в символ

```java
String hex = "4EA840740053E0";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
    String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
    output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
}
System.out.println(output);
```

При использовании Java 8+ можно реализовать это таким образом

```java
System.out.println(Arrays
        .stream(hex.split("(?<=\\G..)")) 
        .map(s -> Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(s, 16)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я получаю не то, что мне нужно. Мне нужно получить результат, как на этой странице. при нажатии кнопки "декодировать" http://crypt-online.ru/crypts/text2hex/